# Python Child Processes Not Always Cleaning Up

Tags: python, multithreading, process, terminate

I'm working on a small bit of Python (2.7.3) to run a script which constantly monitors a message/queue broker and processes entries it finds. Due to volume the processing is embedded in multi-processing fashion that looks a bit like this:

```
result = Queue()
q = JoinableQueue()
process_pool = []

for i in range(args.max_processes):
    q.put(i)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(q, result, broker, ...))
    process_pool.append(p)

#Start processes
for p in process_pool:
    p.start()

#Block until completion
q.join()
logger.warning("All processes completed")
```

Despite the code regularly iterating and logging that all processes had completed, I found PIDs gradually stacking up beyond args.max_processes.

I added an additional block to the end of this:

```
for p in process_pool:
    if p.is_alive():
        logger.warning("Process with pid %s is still alive - terminating" % p.pid)
        try:
            p.terminate()
        except exception as e:
            logger.warning("PROBLEM KILLING PID: stack: %s" % e)
```

I reaped all processes to clear the slate, started again, and I can clearly see the logger very intermittently show instances where a PID is found to still be alive even after it has flagged completion to the parent process AND the terminate process fails to kill it.

I added logger output to the individual threads and each one logs success indicating that it's completed cleanly prior to signaling completion to the parent process, and yet it still hangs around.

Because I plan to run this as a service over time the number of vagrant processes lying around can cause problems as they stack into the thousands.

I'd love some insight on what I'm missing and doing wrong.

Thank you

Edit: Update - adding overview of worker block for question completeness:
The worker interacts with a message/queue broker, the details of which I'll omit somewhat since outside of some debug logging messages everything is wrapped in a try/except block and each thread appears to run to completion, even on the occasions when a child process gets left behind.

```
def worker(queue, result_queue, broker, other_variables...):
    logger.warning("Launched individual thread")
    job = queue.get()
    try:
        message_broker logic
    except Exception as e:
        result_queue.put("Caught exception: %s" % e.message)
    logger.warning("Individual thread completed cleanly...")
    queue.task_done()
```

To iterate the problem. Without any exceptions being thrown and caught I can see all the logging to indicate n threads are started, run to completion, and complete with good status on each iteration. The blocking "q.join()" call which cannot complete until all threads complete returns each time, but some very small number of processes get left behind. I can see them with ps -ef, and if I monitor their count overtime it gradually increases until it breaks Pythons multi-threading capabilities. I added code to look for these instances and manually terminate them, which works in so far as it detects the hung processes, but it does not seem able to terminate them, despite the processes having returned good completion. What am I missing?

Thanks again!

Comment: Please add more detail about "message_broker logic" as it could be causing the problem.

Comment: I need a little help understanding why. The last thing the worker process does is updates the logger. If it is executing this line, and then returning to the point that the q.join() command which blocks execution until all threads have completed then I'm getting very clear programatic indications that all threads completed cleanly and the q.join() call was completely unblocked. This is absolutely happening based on what I see in the logging. My questions of why are quite abstract. Is there a reason why a thread would run to completion and not clean up (small % of time) AND not be terminatable?

Comment: What happens when you try `p.kill()` in the `finally` clause?

Comment: There is no p.kill method.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process

Comment: you should use `os.kill`

Comment: I implemented that this morning, and ran it for over 4 hours where it kept the process count exactly where it needed to be, and could see from logging that the logic was catching "rogue processes" and properly dealing with them... but it feels kludgy. I've been looking into active_children() calls as an alternative to join() as there seems to be issues with join leaving zombies, but I'm not having any luck as of yet. Thanks for the perseverance.